# Is there a way to get the arity of arguments taken by a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I know that you can get the arguments passed into a function using the `arguments` keyword. However, I'm looking for a way to get the arity of arguments that is passed into a javascript function.

something along the lines of:

```
add = function (a,b){}

arity(add) // => 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one way is you can access [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of a function i.e `add.length`, But it doesn't mean that function can take only that many arguments in javascript. You can pass as many [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to a function and access it using the `arguments` object inside your method.

Ex:-

```
 var add = function (a,b){
     var argslength = arguments.length;
 }
 add (1,2,3,4,5);
```

To respond to the comment it cannot be set because it is not writable.

> The Function constructor is itself a Function object. It's length data property has a value of 1. The property attributes are: **Writable: false,** Enumerable: false, Configurable: true.

Comment: And its not always set (especially with native functions)

Comment: Thanks! I only needed the .length property. That is awesome. what happens if I set add.length = 3?

Comment: @zcaudate It is a readonly property you cannot set it, or setting it has no effect.

Comment: @zcaudate That is because you are not in strict mode, see this http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Gfg/ This will throw error, check the console.